# Angular JS and QUnit, Mocking $httpProvider

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular JS and QUnit, and I am struggling to work out how I can mock up the $httpProvider.

In the module, I added a config function so I could add a "no-cache" HTTP header to any request sent out using $http.

```
 app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
        }

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Cache-Control'] = "no-cache, no-store";
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Pragma = "no-cache";
    }]);
```

When using QUnit, this code is executed BEFORE the QUnit's "setup" function, and it doesn't seem possible to inject providers.

Does anyone know how I can safely unit test the "config" part of an Angular module in QUnit?

Comment: try adding [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to mock services